# Convert string to numeric defining the number of decimal digits

Tags: r, string, numeric

From a given data.frame of georeferred points I found the coordinate in a character column formatted as follow

```
"44.524768336 11.4832955249"
"44.6858512233 11.1698766486"
"44.498179364 11.6599683838"
```

To extract the numeric values from each rows I've used the following commands (I'll take the first row as example).

```
res <- strsplit(x = "44.524768336 11.4832955249", split = " ", fixed = T)
res
[[1]]
[1] "44.524768336"  "11.4832955249"

as.numeric(res[[1]][1])
[1] 44.52477
as.numeric(res[[1]][2])
[1] 11.4833
```

In this conversion I've lost 6 decimal digits.
Is there a method to convert strings to numbers setting the number of decimal places without modify any R global setting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't actually lose the digits; that's just how it is being printed to the console:

```
options(digits = 4)
R> as.numeric(res[[1]][1])
#[1] 44.52
## 
options(digits = 12)
R> as.numeric(res[[1]][1])
#[1] 44.524768336
```

---

As pointed out in the comments by David Arenburg you can also use `print(..., digits = <n>)`.

Comment: Or `print(as.numeric(res[[1]]), digits = 12)` as we actually dealing with the `print` function here.

Comment: or `sprintf("%.10f", as.numeric(res[[1]][1])` where 10 can be replaced by however many sig-digits you wish

Comment: `sprintf()` just takes you right back to characters though.

Comment: I've solved my impasse using the print(..., digits = <n>) solution. Thanks for sharing your solutions. A last marginal question: is it possible save in a variables the current number of digit before using options(digits = 12)

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, it is conventional to do something like  `old.opts <- options()` before changing any of your options, so that you revert back to them with `options(old.opts)`. Or if you just want to store individual options you can access them using either `getOption("digits")` or `options()["digits"]`.

Comment: Yes you have well understood. Thanks for this extra explanation

Comment: In the answer #2 I've find a way to obtain as result a number instead of a string.
In my task it work fine but what do you think about ?
Thanks to the  @nrussell contributions

Answer (score 0):

Taking the objective to obtain as results a number and adopting the suggestions provided by @nrussell in the previous answer (and followings comments) I've found the following solution:

```
string.number <- "44.004768336"

# Splitting the string in integer and decimal part
number.part <- strsplit(string.number, ".", fixed = T)
as.numeric(number.part[[1]][1])   # Integer part
[1] 44
as.numeric(number.part[[1]][2])   # Decimal part. Note the effect of the leading zeros
[1] 4768336

# saving the current and set the new setting the "digits" option
getOption(x = "digits")
[1] 11
current.n.dgt <- getOption("digits")
options(digits = 11)

# Combining integer and decimal in a number saving the required numbers of decimal digits
integer.part <- as.numeric(number.part[[1]][1])
exp.numb <- (trunc(log10(as.numeric(number.part[[1]][2])))+1+(nchar(number.part[[1]][2])-nchar(as.character(as.numeric(number.part[[1]][2])))))
decimal.part <- as.numeric(number.part[[1]][2])/(10^exp.numb)
res.number <- integer.part + decimal.part
res.number
[1] 44.004768336
```

A more simple way to avoid the string splitting is the following

```
getOption("digits")
[1] 7
current.n.dgt <- getOption("digits")

string.number <- "44.004768336"
options(digits = 11)
as.numeric(string.number)
[1] 44.004768336

options(digits = current.n.dgt)
getOption("digits")
[1] 7
```